# Xcode Main.storyboard shows weird view

Tags: swift3, xcode8

[image]

not sure when storyboard convert views like this. I re-installed xcode. but no luck. Xcode version is 8.3.2 (8E2002). How do I get previous view.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open storyboard and then go to Editor -> Canvas -> Show Bounds Rectangle and uncheck it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the storyboard content is not getting properly rendered. You can try opening a smaller storyboard and see if the content is rendering properly to know whether it is specific to this larger storyboard.

If a smaller storyboard works, try to isolate the issue in your larger storyboard by temporarily removing scenes and reopening the storyboard. Sometimes these rendering issues can be caused by a particular scene configuration.

The report a bug banner button at the top-right may provide some logs giving clues to the issue.  Feel free to send those to the Apple Bug Reporter